# GitLab DB corrupted, how to recover?

Tags: gitlab

My GitLab database (MySQL InnoDB) was corrupted (something went wrong with my hard disk) and my last backup was performed during the upgrade from 6.8 to 6.8.1

Now I'd like to get GitLab up again but if I try to recover it with

```
/home/git/gitlab/$ bundle exec rake gitlab:backup:restore RAILS_ENV=production
```

I get:

```
Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

This because MySQL is not running, but if I try to start it with `service mysql start` it fails and this is the log:

```
140616  3:28:26 [Warning] Using unique option prefix myisam-recover instead of myisam-recover-options is deprecated and will be removed in a future relea$140616  3:28:26 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
^G/usr/sbin/mysqld: Can't find file: './mysql/plugin.frm' (errno: 13)
140616  3:28:26 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.
140616  3:28:26 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
140616  3:28:26 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
140616  3:28:26 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3.4
140616  3:28:26 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
140616  3:28:27 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
140616  3:28:27  InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation.
InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to
InnoDB: the directory.
InnoDB: File name ./ibdata1
InnoDB: File operation call: 'open'.
InnoDB: Cannot continue operation.
```

How can I restore my last backup without lose my last commits?

Comment: Commit? But mysql has nothing to do with commits, which are stored in bare git repos.

Comment: ok I don't know how gitlab works, by the way I mean I'd like to not lose any kind of data of my repos, not sure how is used mysql and for what is used.

Comment: Understood. Mysql is for users and team management, and access control level declaration. The actual versioned data are in git bare repos.

Comment: Ok, still no idea of how to restore my backup...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the MySQL log

> 140616  3:28:26 [ERROR] Can't open the mysql.plugin table. Please run mysql_upgrade to create it.

You must run `mysql_upgrade` command to upgrade MySQL schema